# Creating table to calculate ages (years) on a future date

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to create a table that will calculate ages, based on a specific date (01/01/2018), and that will leave the cell blank if a birthdate isn't entered.

I've used `=DATEDIF(B1,C1,"y")` but if I do not enter a birthdate, the Age cell will show 118 throughout the rest of the table. My table looks like:

```
*Student   *Birthdate   *Age Deadline(01/01/2018)  *Age
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `IF(DATEDIF(B1,C1,"y")=118,"",DATEDIF(B1,C1,"y"))`

Sorry doing this on a phone so not tested...but should work fine

Comment: It may be simpler to just return a blank if DOB is blank, i.e. `=IF(B1="","",DATEDIF(B1,C1,"y"))` - also allows the possibility of 118 year old students!!!

Comment: @barryhoudini will you post your version as an answer?